# Grouping documents in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am building a chat app using nodejs and mongoose. I need to retrieve chats for a user(logged in user) such that the retrieved data/chats will contain the latest message and the name of the user the logged in user had a chat with. I am not able to come app with a way to aggregate the data since the sender can also be a recipient in a chat. My message schema is shown below.

```
const messageSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    content: { type: String, required: true },
    fromUser: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    toUser: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    users: Array,
    messageRead: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

The purpose of this is to have a list of chats render on the front end which when clicked will open an inbox containing messages between the two users.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the $or operator. This way it will return all elements where the user is the sender *or* recipient:

```
.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          fromUser: ObjectId("<UserID>")
        },
        {
          toUser: ObjectId("<UserID>")
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $sort: { createdDate: -1 } },
  { $limit: 1 },
])
```

**Edit after feedback via chat**

I grouped the documents by using the users array and basically just output all fields as in the initial document:

```
.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      users: ObjectId("<UserID>")
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$users",
      out: {
        $top: {
          output: {
            _id: "$_id",
            content: "$content",
            fromUser: "$fromUser",
            toUser: "$toUser",
            users: "$users",
            messageRead: "$messageRead",
            createdAt: "$createdAt"
          },
          sortBy: {
            createdAt: -1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$out"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: I am getting an empty array.

Comment: Did you set the correct ObjectId in the query? Can your paste the whole aggregation pipeline you are using?

Comment: const chats = await Message.aggregate([
          {
            $match: {
              $or: [
                {
                  fromUser: "62b9abfa6ff45519cd8db9ff",
                },
                {
                  toUser: "62b9abfa6ff45519cd8db9ff",
                },
              ],
            },
          },
          // additional aggregate steps like sorting by createdAt and limiting output
        ]);

Comment: Can you try to pass the user IDs as ObjectIDs instead of plain strings?

Comment: After casting it to objectIDs i am now getting the records back. But I am  getting  multiple chats between two users. I just want a single chat i.e the latest chat.

Comment: Adjusted the aggregation pipeline in my answer. Please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248331/discussion-between-user12504353-and-fabian-strathaus).